# Can't pass password to SSH by getpass

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, getpass

I have code like under:

```
def acces_machine_connnect():
    print(namess.secnd_banner)
    login = input('Login: ')
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
    
    ssh_proxy = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_proxy.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_proxy.connect(Acces_machine, username=login, password=passwd)
    return ssh_proxy
```

It works fine when I'am testing at my home, but in work there is a problem with connecting to SSH but after chaning `passwd = getpass.getpass('Password:')` to normal `input` it works completly fine. Any idea why this might happens? Or how can I change the code to make it works?

Comment: @JNevill I meant passwd = input('Password:') but the problem is your password is visable while typing it. Can we change somehow  getpass() to work like input line above?

Comment: _but in work there is a problem with connecting to SSH_ Well, what is the problem?  What does the code **actually do**?

Comment: @chepner Oh! Thanks for the clarification. I had completely misinterpreted how it worked :/ I will delete my comment.

Comment: @JohnGordon it connects you to the linux server

Comment: I don't think I'm gonna be able to help but I think your question would benefit from adding details of what differs between your home environment and your work environment.

Comment: I wasn't asking what the code is **supposed** to do.  You said there was a problem, so I was asking what the actual problem is.  Do you get an error message?

Comment: @JohnGordon as I said it do not pass the password to the ssh it pass empty so I get creditential error
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

Comment: It seems odd that `getpass()` would return a blank string.  Are you sure it's blank?  If you run a small python script that just calls `getpass()` and prints the result, what output do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `input` instead of `getpass` because getpass can bug depending on the terminal you are using

Here is how to do it:

```
import paramiko

def access_machine_connect():
    print(namess.secnd_banner)
    login = input('Login: ')
    print("Warning: Password input will be visible")
    passwd = input('Password: ')

    ssh_proxy = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_proxy.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_proxy.connect(Acces_machine, username=login, password=passwd)
    return ssh_proxy
```

Comment: Yes I know that as i wrote above, but I'm looking for some solution to keep the pass hiden - I know I can just write function to * the passwd but I would lov to keep it the same as the getpass did.

Comment: You could do a trick to disables the terminal echo with termios while the user types the password, then restores the echo afterwards